# How to apply validation conditionally in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base

 def skip_validation

  if self.type == 'A'
   # skip all validation
  else
   # Do notihng.
  end

end
```

Note : In my test model, I have added validations and callback. I need to apply these validations only if above condition matches.

Can I use `object.save(validates :false)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an `:if` option to do so:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :if => :something_is_true?
```

And `:something_is_true` is a method actually in your method where you can describe your logic.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base # Though I would never name it 'Test'
  validates_presence_of :password, :if => :should_validate_password?

  def should_validate_password
    # define your logic here
    # at the end, it should return 'true' or 'false'
  end
end
```

If the method through which you would like to validate the instance, belongs to the instance, then you can pass that method as a string like following:

```
validates_presence_of :password, if: 'admin?'
```

It would call `admin?` on the current instance, and if it returns `true`, it will validate the presence of password, and vice versa.